# Confirmation dialog with HTML5 button element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button element like so:

```
<button name="command" type="submit" form="frmLandUnits" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete" value="Delete:1:352404725228987" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true">
    </span></button>
```

It's part of a data entry grid in a table which is inside a form. On each row are other buttons like Update, and there's a new row with an Insert button. The problem is that when clicking <kbd>OK</kbd> the form is not submitted. A google search on this turned up nothing that I could find.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form name="frmLandUnits" method="POST" action="https://httpbin.org/post">


<button name="command" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete" value="Delete:1:352404725228987" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true">
    </span></button>
    
</form>
```

The behavior is different than for `onclick` with an `input`. That is why in my opinion this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `form` attribute from your `button`.

```
<button name="command" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete" value="Delete:1:352404725228987" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true">
    </span></button>
```

Checkout [this demo](http://output.jsbin.com/liwalaxaxu)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="frmLandUnits" method="GET" action="www.microsoft.com" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');"  >

<button name="command" type="submit" form="frmLandUnits" class="btn btn-danger" 
title="Delete" value="Delete:1:352404725228987" >
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true">
</span></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a confirmation on the other buttons like Insert or Update.